# Extract data from Json string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I got a string containing Json. It looks like this:

```
"status_code":200,
"status_txt":"OK",
"data":
{
   "img_name":"D9Y3z.png",
   "img_url":"http:\/\/s1.uploads.im\/D9Y3z.png",
   "img_view":"http:\/\/uploads.im\/D9Y3z.png",
   "img_width":"167",
   "img_height":"288",
   "img_attr":"width=\"167\" height=\"288\"",
   "img_size":"36.1 KB",
   "img_bytes":36981,
   "thumb_url":"http:\/\/s1.uploads.im\/t\/D9Y3z.png",
   "thumb_width":360,
   "thumb_height":360,
   "source":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/images\/srpr\/nav_logo66.png",
   "resized":"0",
   "delete_key":"df149b075ab68c38"
}
```

I am trying to get a hold of the "img_url". I have Json.NET installed and I´ve found similar questions here..

for example something like this:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse("{'People':[{'Name':'Jeff'},{'Name':'Joe'}]}");

// get name token of first person and convert to a string
string name = (string)o.SelectToken("People[0].Name");
```

In my case I changed `("People[0].Name")` to `("img_url")`,`("img_url[0])` etc..no luck

This is my code now:

```
public string tempJson { get; set; }
public ActionResult SaveUploadedFile(string test)
{
    using (WebResponse wrs = wrq.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = wrs.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        tempJson = json;
    }
}
```

Do I have to do something with the string before I can extract the value?
Thanks!

Comment: Look closely at your JSON. The "img_url" property is part of a JSON object, which again is assigned to a JSON property. What is the name of that property?

Comment: You mean data? Im lost?

Comment: Yes, "data". Hence you should use `SelectToken("data.img_url");`

Comment: Feel silly now..tried many combinations but not this one..Thanks!

Comment: Thanks elgonzo, though i can´t accept your comment as an answer im gonna mark Sergeys who wrote something similar. Thanks again!

Comment: I am in the process of writing an answer. Mark Sergey's answer, it is good. Pay attention to some differences however: Sergey's code will throw an exception if the "data" object is not in your JSON, whereas *SelectToken* will just return null (not sure whether this would become relevant for your application scenario)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`img_url` is not a property of root object - it's a property of `data` object:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var url = (string)obj["data"]["img_url"]; // http://s1.uploads.im/D9Y3z.png
```

Another option:

```
var url = (string)obj.SelectToken("data.img_url");
```

Comment: @elgonzo thanks. Reading properties with indexers does not involve parsing JPath, but I like SelectToken option for much better readability (and its more safe)

Answer (score 19):

With help of [this site](http://json2csharp.com/)

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
Console.WriteLine(obj.data.img_url);
```

---

```
public class Data
{
    public string img_name { get; set; }
    public string img_url { get; set; }
    public string img_view { get; set; }
    public string img_width { get; set; }
    public string img_height { get; set; }
    public string img_attr { get; set; }
    public string img_size { get; set; }
    public int img_bytes { get; set; }
    public string thumb_url { get; set; }
    public int thumb_width { get; set; }
    public int thumb_height { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string resized { get; set; }
    public string delete_key { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int status_code { get; set; }
    public string status_txt { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

You can also do the same thing with the use of `dynamic` keyword (without declaring above classes)

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Console.WriteLine(obj.data.img_url);
```