# C# Getting individual data from JSON text downloaded from a site

Tags: c#, json.net

I've been searching around for a long while for this, I haven't found any solutions to my issue which is:
I've been trying get a json data individually from a whole source seen here:

```
{"TargetId":0,"ProductType":null,"AssetId":1239281845,"ProductId":0,"Name":"❤️❗️❤️ Red&Black Flannel + Backpack","Description":"Shirt Image","AssetTypeId":1,"Creator":{"Id":124026176,"Name":"TheDestroyerPeter","CreatorType":"User","CreatorTargetId":124026176},"IconImageAssetId":0,"Created":"2017-12-12T19:48:24.693Z","Updated":"2017-12-12T19:48:24.693Z","PriceInRobux":null,"PriceInTickets":null,"Sales":0,"IsNew":false,"IsForSale":false,"IsPublicDomain":false,"IsLimited":false,"IsLimitedUnique":false,"Remaining":null,"MinimumMembershipLevel":0,"ContentRatingTypeId":0}
```

now what I've been trying to do with it is get the Product Name using C# and the product name is "❤️❗️❤️ Red&Black Flannel + Backpack", my issue is that I haven't found a way to extract the data, and when I have I haven't been able to get the right data, because instead if gives me "TheDestroyerPeter"

I've written up code, and deleted it, it was really sloppy and it would take awhile to rewrite, I appreciate any solutions

-whoever I am

Comment: Hi there. You shouldn't have deleted your code since that would give us a starting point. Unfortunately we are not here to write the code for you so please post any attempt first. I'd say use a json library and go for it, shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract data from Json string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233104/extract-data-from-json-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JavaScriptSerializer`  class, which is part of the `System.Web.Script` namespace.

For example :

```
var jsonString = @"{""name"":""John Doe"",""age"":20}";
var JSONObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString );
```

and then `JSONObj["name"]`;  gives you `"John Doe"`

in this case you can use it :

```
    public class Creator
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CreatorType { get; set; }
        public int CreatorTargetId { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int TargetId { get; set; }
        public object ProductType { get; set; }
        public int AssetId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int AssetTypeId { get; set; }
        public Creator Creator { get; set; }
        public int IconImageAssetId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
        public object PriceInRobux { get; set; }
        public object PriceInTickets { get; set; }
        public int Sales { get; set; }
        public bool IsNew { get; set; }
        public bool IsForSale { get; set; }
        public bool IsPublicDomain { get; set; }
        public bool IsLimited { get; set; }
        public bool IsLimitedUnique { get; set; }
        public object Remaining { get; set; }
        public int MinimumMembershipLevel { get; set; }
        public int ContentRatingTypeId { get; set; }
    }
```

use Newtonsoft.Json

```
 var jsonString = @"{""TargetId"":0,""ProductType"":null,""AssetId"":1239281845,""ProductId"":0,""Name"":""❤️❗️❤️ Red&Black Flannel + Backpack"",""Description"":""Shirt Image"",""AssetTypeId"":1,""Creator"":{""Id"":124026176,""Name"":""TheDestroyerPeter"",""CreatorType"":""User"",""CreatorTargetId"":124026176},""IconImageAssetId"":0,""Created"":""2017-12-12T19:48:24.693Z"",""Updated"":""2017-12-12T19:48:24.693Z"",""PriceInRobux"":null,""PriceInTickets"":null,""Sales"":0,""IsNew"":false,""IsForSale"":false,""IsPublicDomain"":false,""IsLimited"":false,""IsLimitedUnique"":false,""Remaining"":null,""MinimumMembershipLevel"":0,""ContentRatingTypeId"":0}";
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);

            Console.WriteLine(obj.Creator.Name);  //"TheDestroyerPeter"
```

Comment: yeah, you see my issue is that I'm trying to extract one of the names, but there are two name values