# How to extract data from this JSON format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a JSON document and I'm trying to extract the individual data from this JSON doc. However, when I try to extract, all I get was some numbers that isn't inside the documents.

Here's the document:

```
user: [{
     serialNo: 1,
     details: [{ name: "John",
             job: "Receptionist" }]
 },
 {
     serialNo: 2,
     details: [{
             name: "Alan",
             job: "Salesman"
          }]
  }
]
```

So I tried doing this to extract the name "Alan"

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var data = objText[1][0].name;
    }
}
```

All it returns me is some number that doesn't make sense, like '123' or '467' etc.

Comment: @Arana why can't you follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233104/extract-data-from-json-string

Comment: Convert your json to c# and its easy to extract.

Comment: take a look at JSON.Net and then make it into  POCO

Comment: @vishuminhas I have tried `var data= (string)obj["user"]["serialNo"]; ` but it prompts error. It say `[ ]` needs to be in int.

Comment: your json seems invalid please provide correct json

Comment: @vishuminhas correct json? this is the json format i see when I open it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look into [Json.NET - Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). it is a package that can be found with NuGet as well, just by typing in Newtonsoft :).

You can then make a model like so:

first solution:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace UsersJSON
{

    public class UsersRepository
    {
        public User[] Users;
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int serialNo;
        public string[] details;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = @"{
  users: [
  {
    serialNo: 1,
    details: ['John', 'Receptionist']
  },
  {
    serialNo: 2,
    details: ['Alan', 'Salesman']
  }]
}";
            var usersList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsersRepository>(json);
            Console.WriteLine(usersList.Users[0].details[0]); // prints "John"
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

second solution:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace UsersJSON
{

    public class UsersRepository
    {
        public User[] Users;
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int serialNo;
        public UserDetails details;
    }

    public class UserDetails
    {
        public string name;
        public string job;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = @"{
  users: [
  {
    serialNo: 1,
    details: {name: 'John', job: 'Receptionist'}
  },
  {
    serialNo: 2,
    details: {name: 'Alan', job:'Salesman'}
  }]
}";
            var usersList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsersRepository>(json);
            Console.WriteLine(usersList.Users[0].details.name); // prints "John"
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Both require you to change your JSON output slightly.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the codes provided. However, when I tried doing the same, I did a debug at `var usersList` part, I got a null from it.

Comment: The code I initially posted was untested, but I have since gone back to have a look at the code, and have got it working but i required me to change your JSON as the string that you have provided is in fact invalid. If you look to my now edited solution, you will be able to see what valid JSON looks like :)

Comment: If you want to have name: and job: as accessors, you will need to use the { name: "name" , job: "job" } notation as instead of [] because the [] notation is for arrays not objects and you cannot use : to define accessors to array items in JSON. You can view if your JSON is valid using this link http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: I've tried out the RAW lines of my JSON on the jsonviewer you have provided. It is able to be formatted. But i'm not sure why in my codes, I am getting null although i'm following the exact steps.. hmm

Comment: So I used the json you provided and put a { at the beginning and } at the end to see if the viewer formats it, and it does, however, Json.NET expects to see curly braces "{ }" instead of square ones "[ ]" when there are names inside like name: "value". I can edit my code once more so you can see the alternative way to structure your JSON

Comment: Also I just noticed that it is correct JSON it was just missing the beginning { and ending }, if you want to use the 2nd solution just change the public UserDetails details to public UserDetails[] details; and it should work the same but you'd just access it through an array