# Extract data from json C#

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have a a api response from Azure Ml which returns the follow json bellow:

**responseApi content**

```
{ "Results": { "id_unidade_negocio": [ { "msgSucesso": "Processamento concluído com sucesso" } ] } }
```

I would like to extract only the `"msgSucesso": "Processamento concluído com sucesso"`

I try the code below, however didn't work.

```cs
var obj = JObject.Parse(responseApi);
var msg = (string)obj.SelectToken("Results.msgSucesso");
```

I didin't try to deserialize the json to a object class, because I don't know the right format  class to create it to be compatible with output json.

Whats is the best way to extract this info from json response?
Or How can I create a class that fit in this json output in other to convert the json to object?

Comment: Deserialize it to dynamic if you don't have the class.

Comment: I tried this alternative as well. It Works. But after the object is created how can I access the atribute that i need ?

When I inspect the object all the data are inside the Root parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24233127/2906166

check above link

```
public class IdUnidadeNegocio
{
    public string msgSucesso { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    public List<IdUnidadeNegocio> id_unidade_negocio { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Results Results { get; set; }
}


var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseApi);
Console.WriteLine(obj.Results.First().msgSucesso);
```

Comment: It worked! Creating the class and then converting to a json I was able to extract the information.