# Extract specific data from JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have the following code in my app (using Newton.Json):

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseValue).ToString();
```

Using the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine(data);
```

I get:

```
{
  "result": "some random string goes here",
  "error": null,
  "id": "1"
}
```

How do I get the string from the `result` part of the JSON in the `data` variable, and put it into its own variable for later use?

Comment: Did you check this question: [Extract data from Json string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233104/extract-data-from-json-string) (and other similar questions here)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a C# class that corresponds to the "shape" of the JSON (same properties with the same data type):

```
public class ResponseType
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

you can do:

```
ResponseType data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseType>(responseValue);
```

and then access each property of that class:

```
string result = data.Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without deserialization.

```
var json = JObject.Parse(responseValue);
var result = json["result"];
```

Open namespace.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```