# Read specific key values from file and add to list/dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, file

So, I have data from my file which is currently getting from the server.

This is part of the format of my file

[{"Table":"Starters","Label":"Starters","Columns":[{"Field":"Desc","Display":"Description",{"Field":"Name","Display":"Starter Name",},
{"Table":"Main","Label":"Main Course","Columns":[{"Field":"Desc","Display:"Description",{"Field":"Name","Display":"Main Course Name",}

I need to read it and extract only the tables and labels.

Can you help pls??

Here is a small part:
public static void getTables() {

```
 var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(String.Format("{0}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path"]));

 using(StreamReader file =
     File.OpenText(serverPath)){
  string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
  AddKeyWord(list, json, "Table, Label")
```

}

```
  }


  private static void 
  AddKeyWord(List<(string, string)> 
  list, string infoString, string 
  keys)
  {
    int lo;
    int hi = 0;
    string[] keyValues = 
    keys.Split(",");

  for(int i = 0; i < 
  keyValues.Length; i++){
    while (hi < infoString.Length)
    {
        lo = 
 infoString.IndexOf(keyValue[i], 
  hi);
        //break condition if end of 
   string
        if (lo == -1) return;
        hi = 
  infoString.IndexOf(",", lo + 
  keyValue[i].Length + 3);

        string value = 
  infoString.Substring(lo, hi-lo);
        
  list.Add((keyValue[i],value));
        
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use a JSON-Serializer and map it to a POCO, which is quite easy within c# ([Tutorial JSON Deserialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0)).
Another possibility would be to use a combination of `IndexOf(String, StringComparison)` and `Substring(Int32, Int32)`.Search for *table* and *tag* with `IndexOf(String, StringComparison)` to get their index and use again `indexOf()` to find the delimiter, in your case ",". Now extract the substring with `Substring(Int32, Int32)`. 

[This answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233104/extract-data-from-json-string) should solve your problem.

This should work. But I haven't tried it extensively.

```cSharp
private static void AddKeyWord(List<(string, string)> list, string infoString, string key)
    {
        int lo;
        int hi = 0;
        while (hi < infoString.Length)
        {
            lo = infoString.IndexOf(key, hi);
            //break condition if end of string
            if (lo == -1) return;
            hi = infoString.IndexOf(",", lo + key.Length + 3);

            string value = infoString.Substring(lo, hi-lo);
            list.Add((key,value));
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you pls help to write the code? Ive tried. Getting errors

Comment: getting errors Current JsonReader item is not an object. Check my edited code

Comment: @user20565161 i can't see any code you added. Are you sure youre using newtonsofts json nuget?

Comment: starts from the 'string json....

Comment: I checked the files formatting, which is not real json. This is why you get an error. - Is there a possibilty to get it as a json?

Comment: @fynmmm, I cant modify the file as its stored on server like that :(

Comment: any way to get around this?

Comment: @user20565161 look at the edit

Comment: have modified it a bit. Thanks though

Comment: @fynmmm, Ive tried with the 2 keys. Does not seem to work. I have updated

Comment: @user20565161 The argument `infoString` represents the string you want to extract the key words from, i.e. the string you fetch from the server. The argument `key` is like you used it, the key value you're looking for in the infoString.
You have to call the function for every key you want to look up.